# Magento 2 : How to create Custom admin theme?

Tags: magento2, theme, backend, custom-theme

How to create Custom admin theme and apply in back end ?

Comment: I want to apply my admin theme to all page like frontend. 

In frontend if I will create my custom theme in inspect element it's show css from my theme but it's inherit parent theme.

Is there any step by step document ?